# FB.ui feed isn't accepting parameters

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, share, fb.ui

I created a function for the FB.ui feed dialog. It works just fine, when I use the standard example from the documentation - but as soon as I try other parameters, it only shows a blank share dialog.

The function is as shown below.

```
/* Share Dialog */
function shareDialog(url, text, picture) {
   FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        link: url,
        caption: text,
        picture: picture
    }, function(response) {});
}
```

All data are fetched through jQuery using the data-tag through a bound click event. The data is fetched correctly - and is parsed through the function above correctly, it seems. I checked using console.log for each of the variables.

```
jQuery('#share').bind('click', function() {
    var shareurl    = jQuery('#share-dialog').data('shareurl');
    var sharetext   = jQuery('#share-dialog').data('sharetext');
    var shareimg    = jQuery('#share-dialog').data('shareimg');

    shareurl = shareurl.replace('http://','https://');
    shareimg = shareimg.replace('http://','https://');

    shareDialog(shareurl, sharetext, shareimg);
});
```

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working? As mentioned - the function is based on the standard example from the documentation, which works just fine. I've tried both with and without the https correction - to no avail.

Comment: the feed dialog is deprecated, use the share dialog instead. the data comes from the open graph tags of the url.

Comment: I found the solution;
- I had been working localhost - and that was apparently an issue.
- After uploading it to the apps domain I'm using, it worked as intended.